# Binary Search Tree. Is my understanding of pointers wrong?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

under deleteNode >> one child / leaf node. why can the *tree be assigned a different pointer when it should be unchanged as the root pointer? What I did was to assign the child node ( noteToDelete->left) to the parent node (noteToDelete), but it broke in some scenarios which i think had to do with accessing free memory. sorry i didn't managed to replicate it again, but the error stated some malloc thing. Additionally, do i have to delete the successor recursively? Can i not just free(successor)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Define the structure for a tree node
typedef struct treeNode 
{
    int data;
    struct treeNode* left;
    struct treeNode* right;
} treeNode;

treeNode* createNode(int data)
{
    treeNode* newNode = (treeNode*)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

treeNode* search(treeNode** tree, int data)
{
    if((*tree) == NULL) return NULL;
    else if((*tree)->data == data) return *tree;
    else if(data <= (*tree)->data) return search(&((*tree)->left),data);
    else if(data > (*tree)->data) return search(&((*tree)->right),data);
    else return NULL;
}

void insert(treeNode** tree, int data)
{
    if(*tree == NULL) *tree = createNode(data);
    else if(data <= (*tree)->data) insert(&((*tree)->left), data);
    else if(data > (*tree)->data) insert(&((*tree)->right), data);
}

void delete(treeNode** tree, int data)
{
    // If tree is empty
    if (*tree == NULL) {
        printf("Not Found");
        return;
    }

    treeNode* nodeToDelete = search(tree, data);

    // If data doesn't exist in tree
    if (nodeToDelete == NULL) {
        printf("Not Found");
        return;
    }

    // If the node to delete has only one child or is a leaf
    if (nodeToDelete->left == NULL) {
        treeNode* temp = nodeToDelete;
        *tree = nodeToDelete->right;
        free(temp);
    } else if (nodeToDelete->right == NULL) {
        treeNode* temp = nodeToDelete;
        *tree = nodeToDelete->left;
        free(temp);
    }
    // If the node to delete has two children
    else {
        // Find the in-order successor
        treeNode* successor = nodeToDelete->right;
        while (successor->left != NULL) {
            successor = successor->left;
        }

        // Copy the data of the in-order successor to the node to be deleted
        nodeToDelete->data = successor->data;

        // Delete the in-order successor recursively
        delete(&(nodeToDelete->right), successor->data);
    }
}



int main()
{
    int c = -1, i, d, s;
    treeNode* tree = NULL;
     
    while (c != 0)
    {
        printf("Please input your choice(1/2/3/0): ");
        scanf("%d", &c);

        switch(c)
        {
            case 1: //insert

                printf("Enter a number to insert: ");
                scanf("%d", &i);
                insert(&tree, i);
                break;

            case 2: //delete

                printf("Enter a number to delete: ");
                scanf("%d", &d);
                delete(&tree, d);
                break;

            case 3: // search

                printf("Enter a number to to search: ");
                scanf("%d", &s);
                if(search(&tree, s) != NULL) printf("Found.\n");
                else printf("Not Found.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
    // If the node to delete has only one child or is a leaf
    if (nodeToDelete->left == NULL) {
        treeNode* temp = nodeToDelete;
        nodeToDelete = nodeToDelete->right;
        free(temp);
    } else if (nodeToDelete->right == NULL) {
        treeNode* temp = nodeToDelete;
        nodeToDelete = nodeToDelete->left;
        free(temp);
    }
```

Comment: Take a pencil and a piece of paper. Draw three rectangles, label one `pointer to to pointer to treeNode`, the middle one `pointer to treeNode`, and the last one `treeNode`. Draw an arrow from `pointer to pointer to treeNode` to `pointer to treeNode`, and another from `pointer to treeNode` to `treeNode`. That's basically what you have for `tree` inside all of your funbctions. When you dereference (use the `*` operator on) a pointer, follow the arrow to get the object it points to. So `*tree = ...` will change where `pointer to treeNode` is pointing.

Comment: Your `delete` algorithm is simply wrong. It always modifies the pointer to the root. This is not what you want.